# String Sorting in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I implemented my own `ls` program. This is a sample output in the terminal:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 2255 May 14 05:54 rc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 27271 Oct 01 05:25 rc.sysinit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 548752 Feb 23 05:34 rmt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 742 Oct 01 14:28 auto.smb
-r-xr-xr-x 1 2346 Sep 16 14:33 iptables.rules
```

Is there a way I could sort this based on the file names? At the moment, I am printing out the data immediately after each check about file info (file type, permissions, size, etc). Do I need to save the info into a container like stl list and then use stl sort? But how do I just sort on the file name using stl sort?

Comment: It's easier to sort *before* you get the file info, when all you have is a list of file names.

Comment: Note that `std::list` has a dedicated `sort` member function; `std::sort` is more useful for e.g. `vector`s and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you are grabbing the file info. If you are just enumerating the container, you will need to store all of the file info stuff into a structure of some kind and then sort the result.

If however you at some point have all the file names and get properties for them, ideally you will want to just sort that list (again storing the whole thing and sorting).

There is an overload of `std::sort` that takes a comparison function, which you can use to allow you to manually compare two items.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to sort the results you'll (pretty much) need to store the intermediate data into some sort of container before you sort.

If you're always (or at least by default) going to sort on one particular field, you can specify `operator<` to do the comparison based on that field. If you want to support sorting on various other fields, you can specify comparison functors for each field or (preferred if your compiler supports it) use a lambda expression to specify the comparison.

```
class file {
    std::string name;
    // ... 
public:
    bool operator<(file const &other) const { 
        return name < other.name;
    }
};

// ...
std::vector<file> files;

// sort by name (default order):
std::sort(files.begin(), files.end());

// sort by a "size" member (which needs to be accessible):
std::sort(files.begin(), files.end(), 
    [](file const &a, file const &b) { 
        return a.size < b.size; 
    });
```